# Submit Buttons + Description Text Area on Website Aren't Fully Clickable

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I've been digging into this for days and have tried all the fixes I could find on Stack Overflow that I'll detail below. Only the left side of the submit button is able to be clicked at the bottom of a form. Some of this is still placeholder, but these two areas should be fully functioning now. The textarea I was able to mostly fix with `display: block` or `display: inline-block`, but it still doesn't let you click the very top of the textarea along the whole width. Thanks in advance!

```css
form#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 23px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

form#contact button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #26a69a;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  border-radius: 23px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
  border: 1px solid #26a69a;
  transition: all .3s;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <fieldset>
    <textarea name="description" type="text" class="form-control" id="Description" placeholder="Description Of Item - Please Don't Use Special Characters Including Commas" required="yes"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <fieldset>
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="main-button">Next</button>
  </fieldset><br>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the CSS so it corresponds to the `col-lg-6` and `col-lg-12` class (or `.main-button` and `.form-control` classes) instead of `form#contact textarea` or `form#contact button` with no luck. Most advice on here was regarding `padding` and `display: inline-block` or `display: block`, both of which already seem to be covered though I tried adjusting them just to see. I also tried adjusting min and max height for the textarea. I'm pretty new to both languages so maybe I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: Works absolutely fine for me on Firefox

Comment: Is there some code we're missing that causes it not to work as intended?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @ZachJensz! So there is a js preloader page and a bit of Python, didn’t want to make it overly complex at first thinking it was just the CSS. I’ll grab that from the backend for you tomorrow and update this!

Comment: Turns out some of the Python that is also involved in under NDA... I'm going to try to get a version over that is ok to share. We are running this with a python backend and perhaps that is the issue if you guys aren't having issues.